# storage facilities at the San Francisco airport

Tags: luggage-storage, sfo

Hello we will be travelling onwards from San Francisco on the 30th of June and will return on the 2nd evening. We would like to leave our heavy luggage behind and travel light. What are the options of storing luggage at the airport, as we will be boarding a midnight flight on 2nd to Boston